# How to playback FairPlay content offline

Tags: ios, fairplay

I am trying to implemented downloading and playback(offline) of hls fairplay content. I am trying out the sample application (HLSCatalog) provided with the FairPlay Streaming Server SDK v3. In that application there are 3 streaming but none of them is initiating FairPlay key download sequence. I suspect the third stream in the sample application points to FairPlay content  but the master playlist doesn't exist at the given url.

So the question is can any one point me to a valid HLS FairPlay content that I test using the given sample application.

Answer (score 0):

In the v3 sdk there is a test m3u8 under `Development/Key Server Module/testing/Test Streams/Muxed/Encrypted/` with the key and master m3u8

Comment: thanks for the info. now I need to figure out how to host this content on the server. I don't have access to the servers I try to fetch license/content from. Do you know if I can host this on Apache server locally on my Mac?

Comment: Any https server can host the files, the AVAssetDownloadURLSession will specify the URL for the files.